# Can I put a span and an input inside a label?

Tags: html, forms

I am building a large form with a dynamic number of fields and I don't want to do this:

```
<label for="foo">Text</label><input id="foo">
```

Normally I would do it but I don't want to fumble with foo's 1-50 as well as incrementing more programatically when the user adds a new row. I [read](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1) that instead of using for attributes, it is perfectly valid to associate a label with a control implicitly by wrapping the label around the control as long as you only have one control in the label. i.e.:

```
<label>Text<input></label>
```

However, I would also like to do a little more styling than this allows.

So can I do this?

```
<label><span>Text</span><input></label>
```

Or is that invalid markup?

Comment: [<label>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)

Comment: Whilst it is very common to use spans within labels for styling- the use of inputs within the label should be limited IMO. One reason for doing this might be for a radio button or checkbox so that clicking the text of the label will check the input - but for a text input - IMO- the label should be separate to the input and related to it using the for = attribute (as you have in your original code) so for my 2 cents - its not invalid - but its not an approach I would take..

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on melancia's comment.
The [MDN label documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) indicates the label element can contain "[phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content)" excluding additional labels. This includes spans.

Answer (score -1):

document type does not allow element "LABEL" here; missing one of "P", "H1", "H2", "H3", "H4", "H5", "H6", "PRE", "DIV", "ADDRESS" start-tag.

The mentioned element is not allowed to appear in the context in which you've placed it; the other mentioned elements are the only ones that are both allowed there and can contain the element mentioned. This might mean that you need a containing element, or possibly that you've forgotten to close a previous element.

One possible cause for this message is that you have attempted to put a block-level element (such as "< p >" or "< table >") inside an inline element (such as "< a >", "< span >", or "< font >").